# OS X Mavericks moving notification bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I just got OS X Mavericks and the new notification bar (as seen in the right of [this link](http://gyazo.com/d5d951ae51de5cc810aa2f5c750b14a9.png)) in the top right is bugging me. Is there a way to remove or move it, so the search bar is the first thing in the top right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [**Bartender**](http://www.macbartender.com/).

This allows you to rearrange and hide menu bar items, including items that Apple prohibit from moving such as Spotlight or Notification Center. It also lets you move items to a secondary bar or to be hidden until a keyboard shortcut is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

To kill the notification bar, type this:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist && killall NotificationCenter
```

If you want to renable it, type:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist && killall NotificationCenter
```

As for moving it, so that the Spotlight function is first, I do not know. You can easily access Spotlight by keyboard using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>**+**<kbd>Space</kbd> and that will quickly open Spotlight, and you can just start typing without having to move your mouse.

Comment: I've read online about the command-space trick for spotlight, but it does nothing for me (Spotlight does not open, nothing changes). Any ideas?

Comment: I knew about that, but it doesn't move it, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: No, you can move icons, you need to hold down command while clicking on the icon.

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry. I didn't read your comment properly. My bad. :(

Comment: All good :) (fills up character minimum)